# Can we prevent Azure LogicApp trigger from firing when deploying

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-group

I've created a script to create new LogicApps using PowerShell and deploy them to my Azure ResourceGroup. It uses a schedule recurrence and calls an action on these specific triggers.

The script works and gets the job done (I get to create and update my LogicApp). My issue however is that the LogicApp is triggered every time I do an update in addition of using the recurrence trigger.

Among things I've tried, I've attempted to disable, update then re-enable, but sadly it just triggers as soon as it is enabled back.

The reason around this is I want to run the action on specific time only, and it doesn't match the moment I'm deploying it.

Is there a way to prevent the Logic App from triggering?

If it helps, I am using the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmdlet. I've browsed the documentation but there doesn't seem to be any mention as to whether I want to run it immediately or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the **Start time** parameter, that should resolve your issue:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer, I wanted to test it out with our prod config and make sure that it would work. Thanks! It worked :)